# enabling and creating roles in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, authentication, authorization

How to enable roles in mvc?? my code is given below and i dont know how to create roles and i want to add it to the databse..

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
    public class UserRightAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            //write your user right logic
            //if user has right to do nothig otherwise redirect to error page.
            string message = "It seems You  are not authorize to view this part of the web site!!!.";
            RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
            redirectTargetDictionary.Add("area", "");
            redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "SaveData");
            redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Home");
            redirectTargetDictionary.Add("customMessage", message);
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [John Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First web.config add following

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    ...
```

Adding roles is the same like ASP.NET for example

```
Roles.CreateRole("RoleName");
Roles.AddUserToRole("userName", "RoleName");
```

Comment: thanx alot..suppose i want to take this value from textbox and everytime it gets updated automatically and the user and role is added then what to do?

Comment: hot pursuit! after 16 months later, you understand that my answer is wrong. congratulations! But I dont understand, what do you want from me? ...

Comment: Still I cant understand you :) Why are you talking about rep. point? I mean your question is unclear :) Be relax...

Comment: your question title is "enabling and creating roles" but your question codes about actionfilter. What did you try? and What error did you get? Please, explain your question clearly. also, Is your problem  "adding roles in mvc" or "me"? I cant understand what is exactly your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Web.config add

```
   <membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="insid" type="int" defaultValue="0"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

> ```
> Roles.CreateRole("RoleName");
> Roles.AddUserToRole("userName", "RoleName");
> ```